# An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
bool emptyline = false;
List<string> arry = new List<string>();
List<int> arryint = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; emptyline == false; i++)
{
    arry.Add(Console.ReadLine());
    if (arry[i] == string.Empty) { emptyline = true;   }
     arryint.Add(int.Parse(arry[i]));  
}
```

This error pops up when I try to run it

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll  Additional information: Input string was not in a
>   correct format.

Comment: See error message: Input string was not in a correct format. That means arry[i] is not an integer when parsing. This may also happen on an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty clear that tells you can't parse a non-numeric string as integer. Try to use `int.TryParse`

```
int val;
if (int.TryParse(arry[i], out val))
{
    arryint.Add(val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code it seems like the string passed into the `int.Parse()` is not a number.

Good practice is to use `int.TryParse("some string", out int value)` the TryParse will return a `true` or `false` based on weather or not it's a integer and you can use an if statement to handle that as you wish.

Also, you shouldn't be using `array[i] == string.Empty` but instead use the string function `string.IsNullOrEmpty(array[i])`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As Rainman and Toni Kostelac said above, error come from

```
arryint.Add(int.Parse(arry[i]));
```

To be more clean, I rewrite your code as bellow (in my opinion), and you do not need to create List of string to store the input data:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> lstVal = new List<int>();

        for (;;)
        {
            string str = Console.ReadLine();
            if (str.Trim().Equals(""))
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                int iVal;
                if (int.TryParse(str, out iVal))
                {
                    lstVal.Add(iVal);
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Input value : ");

        foreach (int iVal in lstVal)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", iVal);
        }

        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
```